# My code is very slow. How to optimize it? Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

```
def function_1(arr):
    return [j for i in range(len(arr)) for j in range(len(arr))
            if np.array(arr)[i] == np.sort(arr)[::-1][j]]
```

An `arrarr` array is given. It is required for each position `[i]` to find the `arriarri` element number in the `arrarr` array, sorted in descending order. All values ​​of the `arrarr` array are different.

I have to write func in 1 line. It is working, but very slowly. I have to do this:

```
np.random.seed(42)
arr = function_1(np.random.uniform(size=1000000))
print(arr[7] + arr[42] + arr[445677] + arr[53422])
```

Please help to optimize the code.

Comment: Please fix the formatting. No need to use backticks for multiple lines; paste as a single block, highlight it all and click the `{}` button on the editor

Comment: `np.sort(arr)` gets performed repeatedly, but the result is never going to change.

Comment: *Why* do you have to write it in one line? (Granted, the assignment expressions of PEP-572 will help you do this once Python 3.8 is released.)

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly sorting and reversing the array, but the result of that operation is independent of the current value of `i` or `j`. The simple thing to do is to pre-compute that, then use its value in the list comprehension.

For that matter, `range(len(arr))` can also be computed once.

Finally, `arr` is already an array; you don't need to make a copy each time through the `i` loop.

```
def function_1(arr):
    arr_sr = np.sort(arr)[::-1]
    r = range(len(arr))
    return [j for i in r for j in r if arr[i] == arr_sr[j]]
```

Fitting this into a single line becomes trickier. Aside from extremely artificial outside constraints, there is no reason to do so, but once Python 3.8 is released, assignment expressions will make it simpler to do so. I *think* the following would be equivalent.

```
def function_1(arr):
    return [j for i in (r:=range(len(arr))) for j in r if arr[i] == (arr_sr:=np.sort(arr)[::-1])[j]]
```

Comment: This code does not work for this example: `np.random.seed(42)

arr = function_1(np.random.uniform(size=1000000))

print(arr[7] + arr[42] + arr[445677] + arr[53422])`

Answer (score 0):

Have a think about the steps that are going on in here:

```
[j
 for i in range(len(arr))
 for j in range(len(arr))
 if np.array(arr)[i] == np.sort(arr)[::-1][j]
]
```

Suppose your array contains *N* elements.
You pick an `i`, *N* different times
You pick a `j` *N* different times
Then for each `(i,j)` pair you are doing the final line.
That is, you're doing the final line *N^2* times.

But in that final line, you're sorting an array containing *N* elements. That's an NlogN operation. So the complexity of your code is O(N^3.logN).

Try making a sorted copy of the array before your [... for i ... for j ...] is called. That'll reduce the time complexity to O(N^2 + NlogN)

I think...

Comment: You should do it right first. You should do it cleanly next. Doing it in one line is a silly constraint

Comment: I applied all your recommendations, but when I apply for such an example, `np.random.seed(42)
arr = function_1(np.random.uniform(size=1000000))
print(arr[7] + arr[42] + arr[445677] + arr[53422])`
 it calculates it already for 2 days ...

Comment: That seems very unlikely. It takes numpy less than a second to sort a million numbers on my machine. Post your code.

Comment: What you're trying to do (for each j, find the index of the j'th largest value in an input array) is basically what R's order function does.

Comment: `def function_1(arr):
    arr_sr = np.sort(arr)[::-1]
    r = range(len(arr))
    return [j for i in r for j in r if arr[i] == arr_sr[j]]




np.random.seed(42)
arr = function_1(np.random.uniform(size=1000000))
print(arr[7] + arr[42] + arr[445677] + arr[53422])`

Comment: Given an array $ arr $, it is required for each position $ i $ to find the element number $ arr_i $ in the array $ arr $, sorted in descending order. All values in the $ arr $ array are different.

Comment: So ... suppose that `rs` was the array returned by your function. Then `arr[rs[0]]` would be the index of the largest value in the initial array. Just read the numpy sorting & searching notes to find the one-liner you need. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/routines.sort.html